# Неожиданный серый квадрат при запуске видео в Android TV

Tags: android, angular, видео, cordova, webkit

Я разрабатываю приложение для Android TV или TV Box на angular и cordova. В нем запускаются различные видео в плейере. Перед запуском видео появляется такое изображение. Потом когда видео подгрузилось, оно исчезает.

Изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я тестировал на ПК, на телефоне, такое изображение не появляется, только в TV Box. Как можно его убрать?

Comment: Я такое встречаю часто в Chrome на Android. Пробовали менять атрибут poster? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку, буду пробовать!

Comment: It's default picture for WebView on mobile devices. Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220624/android-webview-gray-play-button

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет!